# BIGQUERY SQL How to count date range per hour total

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to count total number of placed orders between date range 01 -31 days per hour in a day

Customer_placed_order_datetime

01 01:10:38

01 01:12:38

02 01:14:30

31 23:42:22

Example outcome would be like

Date 01-31

```
                    Date 01-31            total orders
                      1  hour              500
                      2 hour               300
```

and so forth.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  format_datetime('%Y-%m', Customer_placed_order_datetime) year_month,
  extract(hour from Customer_placed_order_datetime) hour, 
  count(*) total_orders
from your_table 
group by year_month, hour
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select datetime '2021-12-01 01:10:38' Customer_placed_order_datetime union all
  select '2021-12-01 01:12:38' union all
  select '2021-12-02 01:14:30' union all
  select '2021-12-31 23:42:22' 
)
```

output is

[image]